# Looking for first record layout of z/OS runnables starting with "IEWPLMH "

Tags: zos

This feels something like an archeology expedition but I have been unable to find the record format of the first record of seemingly all executable load modules on z/OS systems. The record always starts with `IEWPLMH` even with when producing a GOFF format (which I have) runnable. Does anyone have any information on this or a link to it?

Answer (score 2):

The format of *load modules* is documented in the [Load Module Formats](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=facilities-load-module-formats) section of the [z/OS MVS Program Management: Advanced Facilities](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-program-management-advanced-facilities) manual.

But I suspect you are looking for the format of a *program object*, which is not documented, and, last I knew, IBM had stated they would not document (at least publicly for the likes of us).

There are decades of history behind this.  IBM found themselves painted into a corner because customers had written code that depended on the format of load modules not changing.  As of 2011, there were 8 different formats/subformats of program object and that number has no doubt grown.  By not documenting (for customers) the format of a program object, IBM felt they had freed themselves to make format changes (adding features customers wanted) as they saw fit.

You may be able to get the information you want using the [Binder's API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=facilities-using-binder-application-programming-interfaces-apis) or [AMBLIST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=aids-amblist-map-load-modules-program-objects).

Comment: Thanks. I've started playing with the `__iew_fd_open` and related FAST OPEN facilities to get at the information without knowing the file format. Having trouble linking, getting symbol unresolved despite providing `iewbinddx.x`

Comment: Just to add to cschneid's answer, don't forget the UNIX Services "nm" command - it's basically AMBLIST, but in my experience, it better handles some of the newer format executables.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the IEWBINDD facility is definitely the way to go. For USS programs,
When compiling the source, the `-Wc,DLL` option is required. When linking the `-Wl,DYNAM=DLL` does the trick. The example program in the appendix of the  [z/OS MVS Program Management: Advanced Facilities](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.ieab200/abstract.htm) was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [port of GNU binutils to z/OS](https://github.com/ambitus/binutils). It contains open source code that can read/write z/OS Program Objects. It is the only publicly available reference to that executable format of which I am aware.

The most important files are [po64-s390.c](https://github.com/ambitus/binutils/blob/program-object/bfd/po64-s390.c) and [po/external.h](https://github.com/ambitus/binutils/blob/program-object/include/po/external.h).